# Проблема с файлом логов Nginx в Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

Всем привет.

Имею такую запись в docker-compose относительно Nginx:

```
nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - main
            - proxy
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            -   ./nginx/logs/error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Но при запуске докера получаю следующую ошибку:

```
nginx    | nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx    | 2021/07/20 21:06:56 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (21: Is a directory)    

nginx exited with code 1
nginx exited with code 1
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.38/containers/170e3dbc602dbbd9d6ebbe1fd95e83a5959a75be2ef1e35cee6bb8fce84418b5/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "compose/cli/log_printer.py", line 233, in watch_events
  File "compose/container.py", line 215, in attach_log_stream
  File "compose/container.py", line 307, in attach
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 61, in attach
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 400, in _read_from_socket
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 311, in _get_raw_response_socket
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
docker.errors.APIError: 409 Client Error: Conflict ("b'container 170e3dbc602dbbd9d6ebbe1fd95e83a5959a75be2ef1e35cee6bb8fce84418b5 is restarting, wait until the container is running'")
```

Файл ./nginx/logs/error.log при этом существует. Может ему нужно дать права на запись?

Comment: `"/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (21: Is a directory)` — видимо, вы внутри контейнера перед этим создаёте каталог с таким именем. наверно, вы хотели создать каталог `"/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Попробуйте монтировать не файл, а каталог `./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Докер не может монтировать файлы, только каталоги. Есть уже готовый докеризированный образ (`docker pull nginx`), он пишет логи в stdout/stderr, которые подхватывает докер. Смотреть такие логи также через него `docker-compose logs -f --tail 100 nginx`. То есть путь докеризации - писать ошибки в stdout, а не в файл. Посмотрите как это сделано: `ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log` https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template

Comment: Все комментарии помогли. Большое спасибо. Правда остановился на варианте "Попробуйте монтировать не файл, а каталог ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Докер не может монтировать файлы, только каталоги.
Есть уже готовый докеризированный образ (`docker pull nginx`), он пишет логи в stdout/stderr, которые подхватывает докер.
Смотреть такие логи также через него `docker-compose logs -f --tail 100 nginx`.
То есть путь докеризации - писать ошибки в stdout, а не в файл. Посмотрите как это сделано:
`ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log`